# Chrome - disable autologin when launching browser through Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

We are doing automation testing on a intranet application. Chrome browser does auto login when we visit the site (through NTLM login). We need to login as different users through automation test.

We were using the flag '--auth-scheme="digest"' to restrict Chrome from using NTLM.

```
args = ['--auth-schemes=digest']
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, args: args)
```

But looks like this option has been removed in Chrome v41. [Related Issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=374951)

Is there any other way to achieve the same in new version of Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to restrict the AuthSchemes with help of registry. I will still look for a better way to do it.

AuthSchemes can be controlled by registry settings as per this link.
https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthSchemes

I created two files and running disable_chrome_ntlm_login.reg file restricts the AuthSchemes

**1) disable_chrome_ntlm_login.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthSchemes"="basic,digest"
```

**2) enable_chrome_ntlm_login.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthSchemes"="basic,digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

Run "disable_chrome_ntlm_login.reg" file to disable NTLM authentication scheme before testing and "enable_chrome_ntlm_login.reg" revert the Chrome to old state.